# Page goes blank whenever AJAX request is fired

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, bootstrap-4, webmethod

I am working on an application built with Bootstrap 4/JQuery/AJAX on ASP.NET. Whenever an AJAX request is fired on the page (on a button click), **the page goes white/blank for the time the request is in progress** and once the AJAX request is completed, the page comes back. The result data is also populated successfully.

I checked on stackoverflow for any solutions. Most of the suggestions were related to changing any buttons on the the HTML page to type="button". I have also tried setting `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` on button click.

I am using bootstrap buttons on a div. There is an HTML form in the page, but I am not submitting it.

Please find below the sample code for reference.

**JS**

```
 $('#btnAuthenticate').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

       var url = resolveUrl('~/req/getData');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {u:"",p:""},
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                //gets the data here and populates it on a dropdown
                //data is received successfully
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("Error occurred while processing the request : " +response.d);
            }
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-4">
        <form>
            <div class="form-row mx-1">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card mb-4">
                      <div class="card-header h3 font-weight-lighter">
                        <div class="float-left"><span class="h3 mr-2" data-feather="file"></span>Select</div>
                        <div class="float-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary float-right mr-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" id="btnDownloadInit">
                              <span data-feather="download"></span>&nbsp;Download
                            </button>
                        </div>

                     </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Download</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="border border-gray rounded p-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <label for="txturl">URL</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txturl" placeholder="URL here.." required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label for="txtUsername">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtUsername" placeholder="name" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label for="txtPassword">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" placeholder="" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 mt-4 mb-2">
                            <div class="btn btn-primary rounded" id="btnAuthenticate"><span class="mr-1" data-feather="lock"></span>Authenticate</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>           
    </div>
```

**CS**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string getData()
{
    try
    {
        ConnectionDetails data = getConnectionDetails();
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.log.Error(ex);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        throw new Exception("Error occurred");
    }
}
```

Comment: why is `#btnAuthenticate` of type `div` and not `button`?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini It is a bootstrap button. My understanding is that it should not matter if it is a div or a button

Comment: won't need preventDefault or stopPropagation... you need to post the controller code here.  req is controller and getData is function?

Comment: @pcalkins getData is a Web Method in ASP.NET. Controller is just returning an object with connection details. I have updated the question.

Comment: I don't think you've posted enough of the script, markup or the controller to troubleshoot this

Comment: @pcalkins There is no controller for this. It is run by ASP.NET WebMethod (which I have added to the question). All the functions are working fine. Data is also fetched successfully. Only thing is that the page goes white after postback for a few seconds and when the data is received back in the ajax call, everything returns to normal and the data is successfully populated.

Comment: not sure what is happening there... the markup does seem a little odd though.  If you have nested forms it might be attempting to post and then doing something odd.  Why are those input fields outside of a form tag?  Why does the form above it have no data to send?

Comment: also, was there a reason to prevent event bubbling?  One of the things I'm thinking is that there's another handler firing... if there's an event firing on the span, it won't be prevented.

Comment: @pcalkins the other inputs are on a modal popup window that is why it is outside the main form. I was just checking if the button click has something to do with it and added code to prevent event bubbling. you can ignore that.

Comment: You are posting data to: "~/req/getData"... it could be returning something that fires a page load or something like that.  You could also have multiple client side events/functions firing... off the top of my head that's what I would check, but very hard to tell without the full script, full markup and full server-side code.  It could also be something as simple as a CSS style that sets a full white background.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for your suggestions. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: @pcalkins Thank you for your pointers. I checked the code thoroughly and found out that a window.load function in the master page was causing this issue. Thanks again for your time!